# SQL 2005 SP4 Maintenance Plan Not Saving

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2005, maintenance

I am using SQL 2005 SP4 specifically version `9.00.5000.00` it is the `Standard` Version and I am accessing it using `SQL Server 2014 Management Studio`.

I am trying to create a `rebuild index` tasks from the maintenance plan wizard and it fails on the process overview (last) section.

I get this information from Advanced Information...

```
===================================

Saving maintenance plan failed.

===================================

No description found

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.SaveToSqlServerAs(Package package, IDTSEvents events, String packagePath, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DatabaseMaintenance.MaintenancePlan.Save()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.MaintenancePlanWizard.MaintenancePlanWizardForm.PerformActions()
```

I have tried this as both `sa` and my local `domain admin` user.

Any help on how to fix this or if I can rebuild indexed using some `T-SQL` that would be great.

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

much of the Sql community uses the Ola Hallengren scripts to perform Index maintenance.  Especially due to the fact that the scripts allow different levels of fragmentation to be handled in different ways (rebuild vs. reorg).  The scripts are valid for all versions of Sql Server.  Take a look at this link https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html and let us know if you have any questions.